# Minikube can't pull a container from ECR

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to run a deployment in minikube which uses an image from a private repository hosted in EKS which I have access to.

I've successfully run the command `docker pull *.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/*:2021-09-20-1` to pull an image from the private repository hosted in eks.

However, when I try to apply a deployment in minikube with that image, I get the error
`ErrImagePull`  which then updates to `ImagePullBackOff`.

Describing the pod says that the error is `no basic auth credentials`.

I've run the command `minikube addons configure registry-creds`  and then
`minikube addons apply registry-creds` , but this hasn't changed anything. Is there something I'm missing?

I've tried manually creating the secret as well, putting it in the default namespace, and this hasn't helped. I've also attached it as the       `imagePullSecrets: - name: registry-creds-ecr` in the deployment yaml, and this hasn't changed the outcome.

What should I do?

Comment: Still not working, am going to reinstall minikube today and start from scratch

Comment: There's [another possible option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55161480/15537201) related to ECR.

Answer (score 0):

[This doc page](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tutorials/configuring_creds_for_aws_ecr/) says you need to launch `minikube addons enable registry-creds` not `minikube addons apply registry-creds`. Not sure if that's the issue.

Comment: HI, I tried this and it didn't help. I'm going to uninstall minikube today and try again from scratch. Thanks