# Getting ImagePullBackOff when starting a POD is AWS EKS

Tags: docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-ecr

I am getting the following error when my pod is deployed and then it tries to pull the image.

```
Failed to pull image "foyer-api:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/library/foyer-api:latest": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/foyer-api:latest": pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

Here is the Pod Yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: foyer-api-test
  labels:
    app: foyer-api-test
spec:
  containers:
    - name: foyer-api
      image: foyer-api:latest
      ports:
       - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: Do you actually have the full `image: 123456789012.dkr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/foyer-api` name there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pull an Image from a Private Registry click [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)

Basically you need to create a secret using docker credential. For example, using command line

```
$ kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=<your-registry-server> --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email>
```

Then use it in `imagePullSecrets`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: foyer-api-test
  labels:
    app: foyer-api-test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: foyer-api
    image: foyer-api:latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
```

Comment: Would this work with aws ecr? Do I use my own aws information for this?

Comment: yes, will work with ecr, check the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49654457/how-to-auto-deploy-docker-containers-from-amazon-ecr-to-kubernetes-using-jenkins how to create secret for ecr

Comment: I don't think this solution is appropriate for ECR, since you are on EKS (EC2) you can attach a role to pull images from your ECR repository.